# Align roman page numbers in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

When I add the table of contents and have roman page numbering in the beginning, the roman page numbers are not right aligned.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside, openright]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\uchapter}[1]{% add unnumbered chapter
    \phantomsection
    \chapter*{#1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}

\begin{document}
    
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{3}

\uchapter{Abstract}
\lipsum[1-2]
\tableofcontents
\uchapter{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
\uchapter{Tabellenverzeichnis}
\uchapter{Formelverzeichnis}
\uchapter{Symbolverzeichnis}
\uchapter{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\uchapter{Sperrvermerk}



\end{document}
```

Apparent solutions to this problem that I have found online either used packages not compatible to KOMA (`tocloft`) or outdated packages (`tocstyle`).
Is there an option or argument perhaps that I am missing to solve this?

Comment: Your roman numbers are too wide for the available space (macro \@pnumwidth) and are pushing into the margin.  The easy solution is to use \scrbook and \frontmatter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different possiblilties to enlarge the available space for page numbers.

If there are only chapter entries with Roman page numbers, you can enlarge the space only for chapters using

```latex
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  pagenumberwidth=2.55em,% default is \@pnumwidth (default is 1.55em)
  rightindent=3.55em% default is \@tocrmarg (default is 2.55em)
]{tocline}{chapter}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[twoside, open=right]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  %pagenumberbox=\mbox
  pagenumberwidth=2.55em,
  rightindent=3.55em
]{tocline}{chapter}

\begin{document}
\cleardoubleoddpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{3}

\addchap{Abstract}
\Blindtext[2]
\tableofcontents
\addchap{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
\addchap{Tabellenverzeichnis}
\addchap{Formelverzeichnis}
\addchap{Symbolverzeichnis}
\addchap{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\addchap{Sperrvermerk}

\cleardoubleoddpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can enlarge the space for all levels:

```latex
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{2.55em}% default is 1.55em
\renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{3.55em}% default is 2.55em
\makeatother
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[twoside, open=right]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{2.55em}% default is 1.55em
\renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{3.55em}% default is 2.55em
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\cleardoubleoddpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{3}

\addchap{Abstract}
\Blindtext[2]
\tableofcontents
\addchap{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
\addchap{Tabellenverzeichnis}
\addchap{Formelverzeichnis}
\addchap{Symbolverzeichnis}
\addchap{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\addchap{Sperrvermerk}

\cleardoubleoddpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course you can also change `pagenumberwidth` and `rightindent` locally in TOC:

```latex
\documentclass[twoside, open=right]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand*\settocpagenumberwidth[2]{%
  \DeclareTOCStyleEntries[pagenumberwidth=#1,rightindent=#2]{tocline}{chapter,section}%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\resettocpagenumberwidth{%
  \DeclareTOCStyleEntries[pagenumberwidth=\@pnumwidth,rightindent=\@tocrmarg]{tocline}{chapter,section}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\cleardoubleoddpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{3}
\addtocontents{toc}{\settocpagenumberwidth{2.55em}{3.55em}}

\addchap{Abstract}
\Blindtext[2]
\tableofcontents
\addchap{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
\addchap{Tabellenverzeichnis}
\addchap{Formelverzeichnis}
\addchap{Symbolverzeichnis}
\addsec{Foo}
\addsec{Bar}
\addchap{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\addchap{Sperrvermerk}
\addsec{Abschnitt 1}
\addsec{Abschnitt 2}

\cleardoubleoddpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\addtocontents{toc}{\resettocpagenumberwidth}
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

If there is no dotted line for chapter entries, you could change the box for the page numbers to `\mbox`:

```latex
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[pagenumberbox=\mbox]{tocline}{chapter}
```

Additional remark: If you need unnumbered chapters with TOC entries, use KOMA-Script command `\addchap`. For unnumbered chapters without TOC entry use `\addchap*`. You can also switch to `scrbook`. This class provides `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`. Then you can use `\chapter` in the front matter for unnumbered chapters with TOC entries.

Comment: You could use \addtocontents to change \@pnumwidth in the middle of the TOC.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I have added an example with a local change of `pagenumberwidth` and `rightindent`. But of course there are other ways, too.